# javascript regular expression for domain name

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression for matching domain names like these:

```
NS1.MDNSSERVICE
NS.INMOTIONHOSTING
```

And ignore other entries, especially the ones that don't contain any dot(.)

However, the result I am getting is not consistent with my understanding. Here is my code:

```
var regex = new RegExp("^[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+){0,2}$", "i");
"file".match(regex);
```

output

```
[ 'file',
  undefined,
  index: 0,
  input: 'file' ]
```

My understanding is that:

```
^ : match the beginning of line
[a-z0-9-]+ : match one of more occurrence of alphanumeric or hyphen(-).
\. : match the literal dot(.)
```

Since I am explicitly mentioning to match the dot(.), not sure why is it returning the match with keywords like "file".

Comment: Should that be `NS.INMOTIONHOSTING.COM`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a literla notation or double-escape the metacharacters in a constructor notation. A literal notation is preferable here since your pattern is not built dynamically:

```
/^[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+){0,2}$/i
```

See snippet:

```js
var regex = /^[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+){0,2}$/i;
console.log("file".match(regex)); // --> null
console.log("NS.INMOTIONHOSTING".match(regex)); 
// --> ["NS.INMOTIONHOSTING", undefined, index: 0, input: "NS.INMOTIONHOSTING"]
```

Comment: got it. forgot about the backslash plague. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. I think you should have a look at the difference of declaring RegExp with literal and constructor notations at [`RegExp` MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp): *There are 2 ways to create a RegExp object: a literal notation and a constructor.... Use literal notation when the regular expression will remain constant. Use the constructor function when you know the regular expression pattern will be changing, or you don't know the pattern and are getting it from another source, such as user input.*

Comment: I understand the differences. Just forgot about it since I don't user regex too heavily. Thanks for the source